# How to find maximal dimension abelian subalgebra in finite Lie Algebra?

Tags: algorithms, lie-algebras

Is there any well known algorithm how to find maximal dimension abelian subalgebra in finite dimension Lie Algebra? If there is a built-in routine in some computer algebra system, it is the most desirable result...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is. We have worked on such an algorithm; see for example [here](http://www.researchgate.net/publication/225714070_Algorithm_to_compute_the_maximal_abelian_dimension_of_Lie_algebras), and our paper [Abelian ideals of maximal dimension for Lie algebras](https://www.google.at/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCQQFjAAahUKEwiagujTurfGAhVGiiwKHRitDFs&url=https%3A%2F%2Fhomepage.univie.ac.at%2FDietrich.Burde%2Fpapers%2Fburde_39_max_ab.pdf&ei=1ZCSVdrDD8aUsgGY2rLYBQ&usg=AFQjCNE9O8syNXWKKbv4w-i0aEzvn3t8Pw&bvm=bv.96783405,d.bGg). For semisimple Lie algebras, the maximal dimension of abelian subalgebras is well known and easy to compute. The difficult case is this invariant for *solvable* Lie algebras, including the construction of such abelian subalgebras.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That's actually I'm looking for!